# JS: Iterate over an array of objects to update object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to iterate over an array of array objects to de-dupe and sort the data within each. The function `onlyUnique` returns unique values in an array. The problem is, it doesn't work as intended.

```
arr_lists = [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, arr_4, arr_5, ...]

for (var list_obj of arr_lists) {
  list_obj = list_obj.join().split(',').filter(onlyUnique);
  list_obj.sort();
  Logger.log(list_obj);
}
```

The logger results show true (i.e. they are what I am looking for), but the original array is unchanged, although I think it should have been updated.

I've tried assigning the filtered array to a new array... nope.
I know that I could add a thousand lines of code to achieve the results, but that seems silly.

I suspect it's something obvious.

Comment: the `list_obj = ...` line inside the loop *reassigns* `list_obj` to be a new array, so it is no longer a reference to one in the array. So sorting that array doesn't do anything to the original array.

Comment: `split(',')` creates a new array, and `filter` creates again a new array. Your code is not sorting the original array. Unrelated, but why do you do `.join().split(',')`?

Comment: @trincot, great question.  Frankly, I don't know.  I lifted the ``.join().split(',')`` code while looking for an easy way to filter to unique values in a list.  I never examined the logic at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by using `Set` data structure to remove the duplicates and `Array.sort()` compare function to sort the elements in an array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr_lists = [[2,3,5,6], [7,2,5,3,3], [1,5,3], [4,7,4,7,3], [1,2,3]];

arr_lists.forEach((arr, index) => {
  arr_lists[index] = [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => a -b);
})

console.log(arr_lists);
```